# Why are 'preterite presents' called so?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

While reading about 'defective verbs' on Wikipedia, I came across this term – *preterite present verbs*.

> The most commonly recognized defective verbs in English are auxiliary verbs — the class of `preterite-present verbs` — can/could, may/might, shall/should, must, ought to, and will/would (which was not historically in Old English a preterite-present but has joined the class in modern English) [[Source]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb)
>
> The so-called `preterite-present verbs` are a small group of anomalous verbs in the Germanic languages in which the present tense shows the form of the strong preterite, and the preterite is weak. [[Source]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preterite-present_verb#Preterite-presents)

I understand why modal auxiliaries are referred to as 'defective verbs' as far as their incomplete conjugation (lacking an infinitive, future tense, participle, imperative, and gerund) is concerned. But I do not understand why they are also referred to as *'preterite present verbs'*.

*['Preterite'](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preterite?q=preterite)* expresses a past action or state, but how is that sense applicable to all modal auxiliaries?  I don't see how *can*, *will*, *may* and *shall* express a past action or state.

Comment: My understanding is that it's not that *can, will, may* etc express the past, but that *could, would, might* express the present. "Well, I could do that, but I don't want to." But I'm not a grammarian.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: You made a point. But I am confused about the meaning of 'preterite present'. The term sounds like a paradox to me.

Answer (score 3):

The extent to which we can still call these preterite-present, is that they have present-tense uses for the past tense form. For example, while we can use *could* as a straight-forward enough (if irregularly formed) past tense of can in a sentence like:

> I **could** run that far when I was younger, but I **can**'t any more.

We can also use *could* in the present tense.

> I **could** run that far when I was younger, but I **could**n't any more.

Including in forms where we must use *could*, and *can* wouldn't serve:

> I **could** really do with a coffee right now.

Remember, that *can* and *could* are forms of the same word. You said "I don't see how *can*, *will*, *may* and *shall* express a past action or state", and the answer is rather than the past tense of those words—*could, would, might & should* can apply to the present tense.

Now for the history bit!

In Old English there were two main forms of verb; *strong* and *weak*. They differed in terms of how they were inflected for person, tense, number and mood. Indeed, we still have the legacy of this in Modern English, so some people still use the terms for Modern English.

A weak verb would change tense by having a set ending added to it. This is the case with most Modern English verbs (*walk* → *walked*, *watch* → *watched*, *auction* → *auctioned*).

A strong verb would have a change in vowel to change tense and sometimes mood. This is still the case of some of the Modern English equivalents (*ring* → *rang/rung*, *bite* → *bit/bitten*, *come* → *came*, *shake* → *shook/shaken*).

Because there are relatively few strong verbs in Modern English, many people don't use the terms *weak* and *strong* about Modern English, but just *regular* and *irregular*, considering all the remaining strong verbs as special cases.

The two also differed in how number and person worked with each type. There was a third class that would act like the strong for the past tense and the weak in the present tense, in this regard.

The fourth class were the preterite-present verbs, where a form you would normally have with a strong past tense, was used in the present tense, and then the other inflections were done as if they were weak. So for this reason, they had some qualities of past-tense verbs when they were in the present. Hence the contradictory name *preterite-present*.

Old English had many more preterite-present verbs than Modern English. The only remnants in Modern English are the auxiliaries. This was not the case in Old English in both directions; by which I mean that not only where many other verbs preterite-present, but that the auxiliaries weren't auxiliaries in Old English (they also weren't defective, you could say *sculan* in Old English while the closest translation "to shall" or "to should" isn't correct Modern English.

*Willan* was neither defective, nor preterite-present, though the modern *will/would* is both. It was a strong verb.

Comment: Jon, while your answer is very informative and well structured, you seem to suggest that what we refer to as _'preterite present verbs'_ are not actually _'preterite present'_ in Modern English but rather they belong to a class of verbs of Old English. Secondly, it appears that only _could, would, might_ and _should_  can be used in both the present and the past whereas _can, shall, will_ and _may_ can only refer to the present. And that would mean, only a half of the group is actually _'preterite present'_.

Comment: The few remaining preterite present verbs in Modern English are a legacy of Old English where it was both more common and worked slightly differently. *Can* is preterite present because *can* is the same verb as *could* in a different tense, and *could* is preterite present. The term applies to the word across all conjugations. Normally when we want to talk about a verb across all confugations and tenses we use the infinitive, but *can/could* lacks one.

Comment: "_Preterite present_" is an archaic proper name for a grammatical category which I and other linguists would simply call [Modal Auxiliary Verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html), or **[Modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf)** for short.

Comment: @JohnLawler across all languages with them? I know all English modal auxillaries are preterite present, and vice versa, but thought this wasn't the case for other languages.

Comment: That's why _preterite present_ is an obsolete term. _Preterite_ is rarely used as it is, and combining it with _present_ does not make for a good description.

Comment: I think the moral is to distrust the terminology one finds on wikipedia when dealing with peevable grammatical topics, like modals or "moods". There's a lot of zombies around.

Comment: @JohnLawler by your "that's why" do you mean what I said in my comment above was correct, and therefore the term isn't good as a synonym? Or do you mean it isn't used at all?

Comment: I mean that that I've never heard _preterite present_ used as a noun compound that's sposta identify a type of verb.  And that I not only think it's not in general use -- I think it's so obscure and idiosyncratic a term that no linguist would understand it to mean "English modal auxiliary verbs". It's pretty typical of the variety of technical terminology unsuspecting researchers come across and innocently think are normal. Not true for English, alas.

Comment: @JohnLawler do you have another term to refer to the pattern inflection it refers to in Old English? (and that in Modern English for that matter, but while I might qualify talking about it in Modern English with "The extent to which we can still call...", I would have made no such hedging with OE).

Comment: See, I don't even know what you mean by a "pattern inflection". Modals **don't inflect**. They come in forms which occasionally are used for a present/perfect distinction (probably less than 10% of the occurrences of _would_ or _could_, for instance). So _preterite presents_ means as much or as little as (say) _epistemic deontics_ or _necessary possibles_; those are also categories of modal, and much more commonly distinguished.

Comment: @JohnLawler that was a typo for what should have been "pattern of inflection", by which I mean the way they're conjugated. So where *witan* meaning blame as a strong verb is *wat* in the past tense 1st & 3rd person, *witan* meaning know as a preterite present is similarly *wat* in the present tense 1st & 3rd, so the present tense forms are matching what's otherwise used for the past.

Comment: The point is they're **not** conjugated. They have been frozen and contain no inflections. And I'm talking about Modern English, not Old English. Nobody speaks Old English, so nobody can tell you wat was correct or why.

Comment: @JohnLawler but "preterite present" itself is Modern English, and your comment about it being obsolete has me wondering whether this includes when it's applied to other languages.

Comment: Modern English modals are not conjugated. There is no conjugation. There is no inflection. There are 9 modal auxiliary verbs. And I don't know what you mean when you say _"preterite present" itself is Modern English_. Both words occur in Modern English, but the phrase itself is not an idiom.

Comment: @JohnLawler A good two years late, but _preterite-present_ is a perfectly standard and very common term within the field of linguistics. Not modern-day English linguistics, but historical linguistics. Preterite-presents are a group of verbs with specific inflectional patterns that existed in Proto-Germanic and exists in all current Germanic languages, including English—and not just in modals, either: _wit_, though obscure, still has the present tense form _wot_ (no special 3sg form: _he wot_), which is built as though it were a strong preterite form; and the ‘weak’ past tense _wist_.

Comment: @Janus: Thank you. I never got that deep into Proto-Gmc, and certainly don't know all its terminology.

Answer (score 0):

"Preterite-present" doesn't mean that *can, will, may* and *shall* "express a past action or state".

It is just a term used to describe a category of Germanic verbs that originally showed a certain pattern of inflection. (Similar to the terms "strong" and "weak" verbs.)

The basis of the categorization isn't the meaning of the verbs, but the form that they take in the present tense. (The meaning may have played a factor in these verbs originally developing these special forms, and it may have affected which ones retained them, but the term "preterite-present" isn't directly about meaning.) 
Like a past-tense verb, the word *may* doesn't take the third-person singular suffix in the present tense. We say *he/she it may,* not *he/she/it *mays.* This is also true for the ancestors of the word: according to Wiktionary, the third-person singular present-tense form of *magan* in Old English was *[mæġ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magan#Old_English),* and the third-person singular present-tense form of the reconstructed Proto-Germanic verb [**maganą*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/magan%C4%85) is **mag.*

I don't like the wording of the sentence "will/would [...] has joined the class in modern English", as John Lawler says in a comment, it makes more sense to refer to the category of modern English verbs that don't inflect as "Modal Auxiliary Verbs".